# The reputation league goes past the year the site was created because a migrated question: Is this the expected behavior?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

Looking at the reputation league, I notice there is a user who is reported in the league for the 2009, when Drupal Answers was not even proposed on Area 51.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

It seems the cause is [Where does Drupal store the content of a node's body?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/where-does-drupal-store-node-body-content) which was first asked on Stack Overflow, and then migrated.

[image: screenshot]

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I demand that this user be awarded a gold Pre-Alpha badge immediately!

Comment: 1. Edit old question to make off topic. 2. Flag for migration. 3. Become #1 user on site for that year. 4. Profit!

Comment: @John You forgot a particular: The question must be one you answered. `:-)`

Comment: No, I just didn't mention hacking the account of whoever answered it.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed. The [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/where-does-drupal-store-the-content-of-a-nodes-body) still exists, but the reputation league doesn't show any information before March, 2011.

[image: month league]

[image: year league]

(The screenshots don't show a "previous month"/"previous year" link.)